# Will I get raided in clash of clans if I'm not connected to WiFi?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Will I get raided in Clash of Clans if I'm not connected to WiFi?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Wi-Fi or other, if you are online you won't. As soon as you get disconnected from coc (connection lost or closed app) without a shield, you're vulnerable.

Comment: You'll still get raided, because other people still have THEIR Wi-Fi on.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes.**

The state of your device (on/off, connected to wifi/no internet) has no bearing on the vulnerability of your village. However, you cannot be attacked while currently playing Clash of Clans. This is why the game forces you offline for at least five minutes every eight hours.